# How to post multiple object to webapi from xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to post multiple object to my api here is my code, but i dont know how to do with multiple object, with one object its working fine.

I have tried with different option but didn't succeed. What am I doing wrong?

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(contactDetail,);
                HttpContent contactDetailData = new StringContent(json);
                contactDetailData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");


                var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notes);
                HttpContent NoteData = new StringContent(json1);
                NoteData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");


                var result = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://192.168.10.6:56556/api/contactDetails", contactDetailData,NoteData);
```

Comment: does your endpoint accept multiple objects?  What does the endpoint signature look like?

Comment: the code i pasted above its not working actually there are errros in code and my web api code look like this public actionresult postcontactdetail(contactdetail contactdetail, List<Note> note){   }

Comment: "there are errors in code" - what specific errors?

Comment: its wrong what i am trying in code i just need to post multiple object to api one object is simple other object with multiple data

Comment: Here is a link you can refer to (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126833/using-httpclient-postasync-correctly).